# Role of System.out.format in Oracle's deadlock example

Tags: java, deadlock

I was going over several deadlock examples and noticed interesting thing while playing with Oracle's sample: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html.

If you substitute this line:
System.out.format("%s: %s" + "  has bowed to me!%n", this.name, bower.getName());

with:
System.out.println(this.name + " has bowed to me! " + bower.getName());

The deadlock will not longer be triggered.

Can someone explain the reason?

Adding the code from the link above for future reference:

```
public class Deadlock {
    static class Friend {
        private final String name;
        public Friend(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
        public synchronized void bow(Friend bower) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s"
                + "  has bowed to me!%n", 
                this.name, bower.getName());
            bower.bowBack(this);
        }
        public synchronized void bowBack(Friend bower) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s"
                + " has bowed back to me!%n",
                this.name, bower.getName());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Friend alphonse =
            new Friend("Alphonse");
        final Friend gaston =
            new Friend("Gaston");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { alphonse.bow(gaston); }
        }).start();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { gaston.bow(alphonse); }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question. Links in time get broken.

Answer (score 2):

That is caused by a **race condition**.

`System.out.format(...);` is much slower than `System.out.println(...)`.

With `println()`, the string to be printed is built by the caller, so all `println()` has to do is print that string.

With `format()` (or `printf()`), the string to be printed is built inside the method, while the method has the synchronized lock. In addition, the method has to parse the format string, a complexity not present with the `println()` where it's simple string concatenation.

So, with `format()`, the code is slow enough for the 2 threads to enter the methods at the same time.

With `println`, the code is faster, so the probability of both threads entering the methods at the same time is much smaller.

Comment: So is it possible for `System.out.format` version run without deadlock? In case the computer is fast enough.

Comment: @samabcde Yes. Insert e.g. `Thread.sleep(500);` between the two thread `start()` calls in `main()`. That makes thread #2 too slow to cause a race condition.

Comment: So without changing the code, `System.out.format` version should always (or almost always) run *with* deadlock? I am just curious why the author of the example choose `System.out.format`, instead of adding `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: @samabcde `format()` is slow enough that the *probability* of a race condition is very, very high. The article actually says this: *"When Deadlock runs, it's **extremely likely** that both threads will block ..."* --- As for why, you'd have to ask the author.

Comment: Okay, Thx for the explanation.